# Member at n is not an ELF object

Tags: linker, android-ndk, tesseract

I am trying to build a library (Tesseract OCR) for Android.  It seems to compile just fine, and I get a bunch of static libraries, but it fails during the linking phase.

The command is:

```
libtool: link: /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ./.libs/libtesseract_api.a ../ccmain/.libs/libtesseract_main.a ../cube/.libs/libtesseract_cube.a ../neural_networks/runtime/.libs/libtesseract_neural.a ../textord/.libs/libtesseract_textord.a ../wordrec/.libs/libtesseract_wordrec.a ../classify/.libs/libtesseract_classify.a ../dict/.libs/libtesseract_dict.a ../ccstruct/.libs/libtesseract_ccstruct.a ../image/.libs/libtesseract_image.a ../cutil/.libs/libtesseract_cutil.a ../viewer/.libs/libtesseract_viewer.a ../ccutil/.libs/libtesseract_ccutil.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Users/xxx/dev/libs/leptonica/current/android-arm/release/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Users/xxx/dev/libs/leptonica/current/android-arm/release/lib -L./ -L../ -L../api -L../ccutil -L../viewer -L../cutil -L../image -L../ccstruct -L../dict -L../classify -L../wordrec -L../neural_networks/runtime -L../textord -L../cube -L../ccmain -L/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/Users/xxx/dev/libs/leptonica/current/android-arm/release/lib /Users/xxx/dev/libs/leptonica/current/android-arm/release/lib/liblept.so -lz -L/opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/armv7-a -L/opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6 -L/opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc -L/opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib -lstdc++ -lm -lc -ldl -lgcc /opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_so.o  -Os -march=armv7-a --sysroot /opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libtesseract.so.3 -o .libs/libtesseract.so.3.0.1
```

And the output looks like:

```
/opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libtesseract_api.a: member at 8 is not an ELF object
/opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libtesseract_api.a: member at 96 is not an ELF object
/opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./.libs/libtesseract_api.a: member at 104400 is not an ELF object`
...
```

As far as I can tell, `libtesseract_api.a` and related files are valid.  Any idea what's happening here?  This isn't an error I've seen before.

Comment: /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm .libs/libtesseract_api.a

Comment: @auselen : `arm-linux-androideabi-nm: libtesseract_api.a: File format not recognized`.  Aha.  That gives me a clue.  Yes, sure enough, problem is I was using the system `ar`, not the Android version.  Fixing that brings up a slew of link errors, but that's much easier to address.  Progress update when I get the thing working.  Thanks.

Comment: np! adding it as an answer and you should also ask other questions as different threads. it would be good to resolve this one. Can you accept / upvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have the right archive type by `nm`

```
.../arm-linux-androideabi-nm .libs/libtesseract_api.a
```

You should use the right format.

Answer (score -1):

After adding the following to `PATH`, it link success :

```
$ANDROID_NDK/toolchain/bin
```